# NotSupportedException gets thrown

Tags: c#, file-io

I am using C# to create a function to write data to a file in File System, and reate it and repeat function if file doesn't exist.

The first method of just writing the data is working. But the second method, if the file is not present and the program has to first create it, isn't working. It **creates the file** but at the very same time throws an exception to me in Visual Studio saying

> System.NotSupportedException is unhandled

I am using the exact copy of code that the MSDN is having.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is what I am using in my second code block,

```
// Create file!
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(file))
{
   Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("some text in the file.");
   // Add some information to the file.
   fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
}
// Continue again with the request. 
createFile(file);
```

The method declaration (if required) is as

```
private static void createFile (string fileName) {
   string file = "C:\\Users\\AfzaalAhmad\\Documents\\" + fileName + ".txt";
   /* two methods here */
}
```

The Image is as: (Note that there is no error in the path of file) I have used

```
Console.Write(file); // to get the path, and its OK!
```

See it in the image below ↓

[image]

Please note, that it does create the file in the Documents folder. But throws this exception. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where exactly is the exception thrown?

Comment: You can see that in the Image I have included, the yellow highlighted line

Comment: Could you please provide value of `file` when exception occurs. It's hard to see on screenshot

Comment: Sure! .. I have added the file variable to the method. It is a local variable for the method `createFile`. :) So I have appeneded it just next to the declaration

Answer (score 2):

Note the detail in the exception report: "The given path's format is not supported."

Also look at the contents of your variable `file` - it appears to be @"C:\Users\AfzaalAhmad\Documents\C:\Users..." - i.e. it contains the path twice.

So even though the operating system might have managed somehow to create some sort of file, the filename does not contain a valid value.

[edit] `createFile(file);` and `Console.Write(file);` are both taking the value @"C:\Users\AfzaalAhmad\Documents\dsg b.txt" but your method `createFile` is then adding the path a second time. Change it to simply:

```
private static void createFile (string file) {
   /* two methods here */
}
```

Comment: I checked this twice, this time by writing the value of `file` too. And look, the value in the File is correct. And still I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a exact look at the Exception message and the value of your file variable! There is your error!